# I need to return all fields from the first instance - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to retrieve the all fields from the first instance of an item in a sales order table.

```
    Item    Order Date  Order Qty
    Item1    17/09/2013  1
    Item1    20/09/2013  2
    Item2    16/09/2013  2
    Item2    17/09/2013  1
    Item3    20/09/2013  3
    Item3    20/09/2013  2
    Item3    20/09/2013  1
```

The records in bold are the ones I am after. My staging table is already sorted by order date (and order qty later on).

`Select DISTINCT` and `Select GROUP` are not suitable as I need to return all the field (there are more that are not shown) and I do not want the total order quantity.

I would greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one using [FIRST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions048.htm#sthref1286) function.

```
select item,
      min(orderdate) keep(dense_rank first order by orderdate, orderqty desc),
      min(orderqty) keep(dense_rank first order by orderdate, orderqty desc)
from items
group by item;
```

Sample [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7edcd/1).

Comment: I should have shown the other fields like Order Type and Order NUmber on my sample table. Is there a way to incorporate those fields into your query without getting a NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION error?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get first occurrence without any order use the below. But if you want to order based on date and quantity, add that in the order by class of row_number function.

```
 Select Item, Order_Date, Order_Qty from 
(select Item, Order_Date, Order_Qty, 
row_number() over(partition by Item order by null) rn
from table1) a where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.*
from your_table t
inner join
(
   select x.Item, min(x."Order Date") as mod
   from 
   (
      select Item, "Order Date", max("Order Qty")
      from your_table
      group by Item, "Order Date"
   ) x
   group by x.Item       
) y on y.item = t.item and y.mod = t."Order Date"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt answer. I will give this a try. However, I am actually after the oldest order and will only care about the order qty (need biggest order) should there be multiple orders on the day of the oldest order. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Hi again. I have tried it but it is giving me all the orders for an item for the oldest day. It did, however, stripped all the orders for later days. I guess I will have to do the above again, this time using max (orderqty).

Comment: I did a second inner join but then I have orders on the same day with the same order quantities so I am still getting multiple records for some items.